# VBA Pivot tables accessing column headers

Tags: vba, excel-2010

Hi I am using excel 2010 VBA on windows 7. How do I access the column headers for a given pivot table.

For Example given the pivot table below

```
            Column Labels
            -------------
Row Labels  Col1          Col2         Col3
----------
Year 1      Value 1      Value 4      Value 7

Year 2      Value 2      Value 5      Value 8

Year 3      Value 3      Value 6      Value 9
```

I am trying to access col1, col2, col3 then I want to read in all the values for that given column using a pivot table in VBA. I can't seem to be able to grab the column labels though? As well once I  have checked the column exists I would want to be able to select the values under that given column. Any help would be awesome!

So what I am asking is how do I check lets say col1 exists as a column and then print out value 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: Helpful reference: https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/

Comment: Thanks a ton! I don't know why but I couldn't find anything that actually gave graphical examples :P

Answer (score 0):

I usually add this comment box below the procedure that creates the Pivot tables.

```
'
' PIVOT Tables 
' These are created programatically.
'
' Relative references are used throughout.  Hard coded cell addresses are avoided.
' This allows it to continue to work with future data that expands/contracts either the rows or the columns.
'
' In this PIVOT Table example, there are six (6) ranges shown.
' By setting a variable equal to the range, and using REZISE and OFFSET functions,
'   any address can be developed relative to these ranges.
'         Dim rBody as Range
'   e.g.  rBody = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").DataBodyRange
'         6   = rBody.Row
'         129 = rBody.Row + rBody.Rows.Count - 1
'          26 = rBody.Column + rBody.Columns.Count - 1
'         E6  = rBody.Resize(1,1)
'         AE6 = rBody.Resize(1,1).Offset(0,rBody.Columns.Count)
'
'/--------------------------------------------------\
'|    TABLE1 and TABLE2 refer to (A3:AD129)         |
'|                /--------------------------------\|
'|  A3            | E3                             ||
'|                |          COLUMN (E3:AD5)       ||
'|  A4            | E4                             ||
'| |------------\ |/------------------------------\||
'| |A5 B5 C5 D5 | ||E5       LABEL             AD5|||
'| |            | \================================/|
'| |            | /--------------------------------\|
'| |    ROW     | | E6                         AD6 || AE6
'| |            | |                                ||
'| |            | |           BODY                 ||
'| |            | |                                ||
'| |A129    D129| | E129                     AD129 ||
'| \------------/ \--------------------------------/|
'\--------------------------------------------------/
```

Comment: Ok, but my concern is that the pivot table size changes which won't update the ranges.

Comment: By using DataRangeBody, it knows what the current ranges are for this time.  Then with Rows, Columns, Resize, Offset, etc you can address any part of the PivotTable.